# MySQL - invalid number of fields for SHOW SLAVE HOSTS

Tags: mysql, replication

I'v recently had to upgrade my MySQL Master database from 5.0 to 5.5. Everything went fine, except that now one of my slave databases is refusing to connect citing the following error:

```
'the master returned an invalid number of fields for SHOW SLAVE HOSTS'
```

This slave is running MySQL 5.0.51. I tried upgrading it to 5.0.91. but that made no difference. I have other slaves using 5.0.81, and they are all fine.

All databases are on Windows. Does anybody know of a way to get round this, without starting from scratch?

Comment: http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/123-mysql-replication-gotchas

Comment: I saw that, but all it says is that an upgrade to v5.0.77 fixed it. It doesn't say how it fixed it. I also upgraded to v5.0.91, ran mysql_upgrade, but it made no difference.